# How to fix RenderFlex overflowed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I was browsing [Uplabs](https://www.uplabs.com) and find a[Login Ui/UX](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/login-ui-ux) design by
[Yogesh Solanki](https://www.uplabs.com/yogesh_001) and
implemented in [Flutter](https://flutter.io/).

While writing that app I face one problem:

1. RenderFlex overflowed

### 1. RenderFlex overflowed

The error message was `A RenderFlex overflowed by 31 pixels on
the bottom.

**[Login UI Source Code](https://github.com/sur2548/login-ui)**

[image]

`How Do I Fix It?`

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your code and used widgets. One way is to wrap root widget into `SingleChildScrollView`.

It can be another solution - you better paste your code

**UPD**

Inside `build` method of `AuthBody` change `Column` to:

```
ListView(children: <Widget>[
  _buildHeader(),
  _buildForm(context),
  _buildForgetButton(),
],)
```

Comment: When I used `SingleChildScrollView` there was nothing but white emtpy screen.

Comment: Try to wrap `Column` in it inside `AuthBody` class. Or change `Column` to `ListView`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I replace `Column` with `ListView`, Now the error is **Incorrect use of `ParentDataWidget`. Expanded widgets must be placed inside `Flex` widgets.**

Comment: It's because of `Spacer` - you need to remove it

Comment: Any other way to achieve the design aspects without using `Spacer`

Comment: I don't see another. You can replace `Spacer` by `SizedBox` or something like this